# Tab Bar Icons not vertically centered React Native Navigation

Tags: ios, typescript, react-native, expo, expo-go

When testing my react native app (with expo) through the expo go IOS app the icons are not vertically centered, however when testing on web they are vertically centered. I have tried giving each icon a parent div and centering it vertically, giving it a TabBarIconStyle of textAlignVertical: center, and textAlign: center, everything I can think of to vertically align these icons.

My Navigator:

```js
<TabNav.Navigator screenOptions={TabNavOptions}>
                <TabNav.Screen
                    name="Home"
                    component={HomeScreen}
                    options={{
                        tabBarIconStyle: { textAlignVertical: "center", textAlign: "center" },
                        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                            <View style={{}}>
                                <Ionicons name="home" color={color} size={size} style={{ textAlignVertical: "center" }} />
                            </View>
                        ),
                    }}
                />
                <TabNav.Screen name="Workouts" component={HomeScreen} options={{ tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => <Ionicons name="barbell" color={color} size={size} /> }} />
                <TabNav.Screen name="Exercises" component={HomeScreen} options={{ tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => <Ionicons name="bicycle" color={color} size={size} /> }} />
            </TabNav.Navigator>
```

My screen options for the Navigator:

```js
const TabNavOptions: BottomTabNavigationOptions = {
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
        tabBarActiveTintColor: "#4B7079",
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: "#FFFFFF",
        tabBarStyle: { width: "90%", height: 60, position: "absolute", left: "5%", bottom: 30, borderRadius: 100, borderTopWidth: 0, backgroundColor: "#75B1BC" },
    };
```

This is what it looks like on web (and what it should look like)

[image]

This is what it looks like on expo go

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I managed to fix this issue with `paddingBottom: 0` within the Navigator options, not sure why it only appeared on IOS would love insight if someone has an idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the styling of the parent view of each icon:

```
{flex: 1, alignItems: "center" }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps we can debug what's going on if you're curious. If you set the background of the parent views go green can you verify that they fill up the entire height of the tab bar?

Comment: when paddingBottom: 0 isnt set they do on web but don't on IOS, not sure why only shows padding for IOS but that was the root of it.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was the container that holds the icons inside the Bottom tab is small in size so I had to give it the same height of the bottom bar and it worked

```
screenOptions={{
   tabBarItemStyle:{height:60},
}}
```